# How to do a Running (Streaming) reduceByKey in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I'm using the `textFileStream()` method in the Python API for Spark streaming to read in XML files as they're created, map them into an XML ElementTree, take the "interesting" items from the ElementTree and `flatMap` them into a dictionary (key: value), then I do a `reduceByKey()` to aggregate counts for each key.

So, if the key is a string network name, the value might be a packet count.  Upon reducing, I'm left with the total packet count for each network (key) in my dictionary.

My problem is I'm having trouble streaming this.  Instead of keeping a running total it re-computes the computation each time.  I think it's a paradigmatic issue for me but I'm wondering if someone can please help me stream this analytic correctly, thanks!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example with what exactly you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the solution was to use `updateStateByKey` [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html)  This allows you to merge the results from the previous step to the data in the current step.  In other words, it allows you to keep a running calculation without having to store the entire RDD and having to recompute every time data is received.